# PHP: Output multiple line command-line outputs as different lines

Tags: php, command-line, command, lines

PHP: Output multiple line command-line outputs as different lines.


Sorry if the title is difficult to understand. Basically I want my output like A, instead of B. It currently looks like B. I have tried nl2br. The script I am trying to run is:

Script:

```
echo "Virus Scan Results:";
$scanme = system('cd /var/www/upload/files; clamscan --remove=yes '.$furl);
printf(nl2br($scanme));
```

A:

```
802931t_e_s_t.txt: OK 
----------- SCAN SUMMARY ----------- 
Known viruses: 574585 
Engine version: 0.95.1 
Scanned directories: 0 
Scanned files: 1 
Infected files: 0 
Data scanned: 0.00 MB 
Data read: 0.00 MB (ratio 0.00:1) 
Time: 2.352 sec (0 m 2 s) 
Time: 2.352 sec (0 m 2 s)
```

B:

```
802931t_e_s_t.txt: OK ----------- SCAN SUMMARY ----------- Known viruses: 574585 Engine version: 0.95.1 Scanned directories: 0 Scanned files: 1 Infected files: 0 Data scanned: 0.00 MB Data read: 0.00 MB (ratio 0.00:1) Time: 2.352 sec (0 m 2 s) Time: 2.352 sec (0 m 2 s)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why are you using nl2br if this is on the command line?

nl2br outputs `<br />` tags for new lines... which would have no meaning on command line

**Edit**

Two things:

**1** try

```
system('cd /var/www/upload/files; clamscan --remove=yes '.$furl, $scanme);
```

**2** You may want to use the [exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function instead of system

e.g.

```
exec('cd /var/www/upload/files; clamscan --remove=yes '.$furl, $scanme);
$scanme = implode("\n",$scanme);
```

exec  ( string $command  [, array &$output  [, int &$return_var  ]] )

Comment: The result is:

<pre>
733141t_e_s_t.txt: OK ----------- SCAN SUMMARY ----------- Known viruses: 574585 Engine version: 0.95.1 Scanned directories: 0 Scanned files: 1 Infected files: 0 Data scanned: 0.00 MB Data read: 0.00 MB (ratio 0.00:1) Time: 2.305 sec (0 m 2 s)

Time: 2.305 sec (0 m 2 s)
</pre>

It seems to only affect the last line. Got any other ideas?

Comment: 733141t_e_s_t.txt: OK ----------- SCAN SUMMARY ----------- Known viruses: 574585 Engine version: 0.95.1 Scanned directories: 0 Scanned files: 1 Infected files: 0 Data scanned: 0.00 MB Data read: 0.00 MB (ratio 0.00:1) Time: 2.305 sec (0 m 2 s)


Time: 2.305 sec (0 m 2 s)

Comment: Works now, it seems like the $scanme was actually outputting the data without an echo or printf. Thanks for the help.

Comment: no worries. the docs for those functions say system, exec, etc return a string. but it's the "last" line returned. The optional second/third parameter is for an output var.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just printing the output of the command directly?

```
echo "Virus Scan Results:";
echo exec('cd /var/www/upload/files; clamscan --remove=yes '.$furl);
```

PS. You really should sanitise the input like so (if you are not doing so already):

```
$furl = escapeshellarg($furl)
```

[escapeshellarg()](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) - Escape a string to be used as a shell argument

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on the commandline, a newline is represented as '\n', or '\r\n' in a Windows environment. So make sure there is a \n at the end of each line, and you should get the output you want.
Edit:
Tom: Oops. Fixed.